UWP Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer: How to sue MediaPlayer to play an AudioCD
I have been trying to use MCI to play audio cd's and while it will play the audio as soon as I use MCI_CLOSE I get an exception. Looking at the Microsoft site and MCI is deprecated and supposedly I should be using MediaPlayer
"MCI, is a legacy feature. It has been superseded by MediaPlayer. MediaPlayer has been optimized for Windows 10 and Windows 11. Microsoft strongly recommends that new code use MediaPlayer"
I can not figure out how to get Media Player to play an audio track from a cd. I can get it to play a wav file using MediaSource CreateFromUri and specifying file:/// but I can't get it to open or play a cd track. Does anybody know if this is possible.
I have tried the E:\Track01.cda and I have tried "cdda:///E:/" which is how you open an audio cd using libvlc.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

According to the introduction of the .cda file, it cannot be opened directly in UWP MediaPlayer. It is recommended to extract the audio file from the cd first, convert .cda to .wav or .mp3 file.

The .cda files do not contain the actual PCM sound wave data, but
instead tell where on the disc each track starts and stops. If the
file is "copied" from the CD to a computer, it cannot be used on its
own because it is only a shortcut to part of the disc.


Yes, I realise the .cda isn't actually wav data and is just Microsoft visualising the contents for the user, I was hoping that the MediaPlayer would have functionality to play the data. I looked at the Source for vlc and it uses IOCTL to read the wave data and then stream it to the player. I was hoping that there was something similar in MediaPlayer rather than me having to grab the buffer using IOCTL and then send that to the Media Player using streaming,

I'd suggest you submit a feature request about this feature in the Feedback Hub.
You could find the Feedback Hub in the Start Menu. Please select Developer Platform-> API Feedback as the category when you submit your request.
The related team will check the request. After you submit the request, please share your link, I will help you submit this request as well.

Thanks for the suggestion. I have added the request. https://aka.ms/AAq33ka
